# Index and Slicing. Checking to see if any items occurred twice

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Lets say you had a list

```
List1(1,2,2,3,4)
```

What code would you use to check if a number occurred twice

Comment: Depends, is the list guaranteed to be sorted, as in your example, or not?

Comment: A specific number or any number?  Exactly twice or at most twice?

Comment: It could be three times or four or whatever

Comment: Please provide more details. Do you care about the number that is duplicated? Or do you just want to see if *any* duplicate exists.

Comment: Just checking if a number(any) occurs more than once

Comment: Are they always numbers and are they from a fixed range?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object to get a list of all duplicated elements:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> l = [1,2,2,3,4]
>>> 
>>> [k for k,v in Counter(l).iteritems() if v > 1] 
[2]
```

If you *just* want to check if a duplicate exists, but don't care what that duplicate actually is, then compare the length of the list with the length of the set of elements contained in the list:

```
>>> len(l) != len(set(l))
True
```

If there are duplicates, the length of the set would be smaller than that of the list. If there are not, the two lengths will be equal.

Comment: Downvoter: please leave a comment. I'd like to know what's wrong with this answer.

Comment: Aye, that was me.  The answer doesn't short circuit, you use `l` as a variable name, and there's no mention that this approach requires elements to be hashable.

Comment: @wim I will address your concerns one by one. 1) You are correct that the answer does not short-circuit. The OP has not told us what size of lists he plans on using, and so I presumed that efficiency would not be a major factor here. I stand by this, because I am not going to sacrifice the readability and simplicity of that one line for efficiency that may not be needed. Of course, my assumption may be incorrect, in which case the OP is free to use a different approach. (to be continued)

Comment: If the OP times both a short-circuit-esque approach against this and arrives at the conclusion that there is a serious time problem, he then (and *only* then) has enough reason to switch, I would assert. I'd also like to point out that in many cases programming time is more valuable than CPU time, and the time it takes to write that one line is essentially 0.

Comment: 2. The conviction that it's bad to use `l` as a variable name in an example snippet is an absurd one, I must say. I agree with you that in any real code `l` can be inappropriate, and variables should have more descriptive names. In small snippets however, it just reduces clutter and gets the idea across easier.

Comment: 3. You're right in saying that elements must be hashable for this to work. However, I think it's safe to assume that the list elements will indeed be integers, as is the case with the OP's example list.

Comment: The issue about `l` is not that you should use a more descriptive name, but that it's indistinguishable from `1` in some cases.  If you think this is absurd, note the official style guide advises to [never](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) use `l` this way.

Comment: @wim upvoted to cancel out your rather harsh and pointless downvote for what is a decent answer. You didn't downvote the other answer that doesn't mention the elements must be hashable?

Answer (score 5):

The problem with `Counter(List1)` and `set(List1)` is that they can't short ciruit. So if List1 had a million items, you need to process the entire list before you get your answer

Suppose we have

```
List1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]

def has_duplicate(List1)
    s = set()
    for item in List1:
        if item in s:
            return True
        s.add(item)
    return False
```

Now the function can return after looking at just 3 items

This is fine if `List1` only contains hashable items. If there are non-hashable items, you can extract them into a separate list and just the `.count()` method in @Christian's answer

If someone really needs to do this fast, the same logic could be used to make a version of the `set` constructor and compiled into native function.

Comment: It's important to note that while this does short circuit, it's also implemented in python.  It will take longer on failures than the other two methods.  Depending on your use case, how many items are in the list, and how often you expect to find a duplicate, either way may be faster.  It's important to test, if you're worried about performance.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity, Yes it's hard to have a single best answer when the question doesn't cover all the unknowns. There's also the complication that performance will vary across different Python implementations.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to test whether or not any element is repeated, but you don't care which ones they are, you can simply do:

```
len(list) == len(set(list))
```

But this may or may not be the most efficient implementation.